# Get a list of subprojects from Jenkins REST API

Tags: python, rest, jenkins

I am writing a python script which accepts a job url for a Jenkins job as a parameter, and I'd like to get back a list of all the subprojects for that specific job. I haven't been able to find a way to do this yet, so I was wondering if anyone else has ever had to do this? Is there some reference in the REST API that I can use or does it just come down to screen scraping?

For example, I have project A at the top and it is responsible for kicking off subprojects B, C, D, E... and I'd like to be able to access the urls for these subprojects through the main job A. What are my options? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34784949/947784 let me know it it helped or not.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I based my solution off of it. It should be marked as the correct answer.