# Jenkinsfile Pipeline DSL: How to Show Multi-Columns in Jobs dashboard GUI - For all Dynamically created stages - When within PIPELINE section

Tags: groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, dashboard

**Jenkins** 2.89.4 rolling

I saw almost all stackoverflow posts which show how we can successfully run parallel steps/stages (using list/maps etc) --OR hardcoding them directly --OR even create dynamic stages for Jenkinsfile (as seen in this post: [Scripted jenkinsfile parallel stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834998/scripted-jenkinsfile-parallel-stage))

**My requirements are:**

1. A pipeline which builds N. no of projects under "BUILD" steps i.e. ***parallel builds on each of those projects***. i.e. it runs Gradle on all N projects. Here I have a Jenkinsfile which was created by a declarative JOB DSL Groovy. Here my Gradle projects are not set as multi-projects so I can't call the top level gradle and say, Gradle please do your parallel magic (within Gradle).
2. I want to run build of these N projects in their ***own separate parallel dynamically created stages (GUI Columns)*** as seen in jenkins job's dashboard.
3. I want to see the output of (Gradle build/console) each project's build separately i.e. ***I don't want to mix the console output of each projects build which are running in parallel in just ONE COLUMN*** (i.e. column named `BUILD`).
4. In this URL https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/ I see, how you can run parallel stages/steps but in doing so, either it's mixing those parallel step's output in just one column (I mean under *BUILD* column) --OR if you want it under separate stages/columns (i.e. the post says *Test on Linux or Windows* ***separately*** then you are still **hard-coding all the stages/steps** in Jenkinsfile early on (*rather than using just a list or array hash* which I'd prefer to update for adding more or less stages / parallel steps as in my case, they all follow the same standard). ***What I want is to just update in one place How many steps and what are all of the stages in just one place (list/array).***
5. I'm ***not*** using *[Jenkins Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/)* for now.

Usually if you have parallel steps within a stage, their console std output for all steps gets mixed into one console output / stage/column when you click to see the console output for that given parallel step/stage; When you hover over the BUILD column (*assuming there were parallel steps in BUILD stage*) in job's dashboard (std output for all those steps is mixed up and very hard to see individual project step's console output just for a given step/stage).

If we want to create separate stages (dynamically) then Jenkins should be able to show console output of a given step/dynamic stage within the parallel section (i.e. each column should show their own project's build console output).

Using the above [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834998/scripted-jenkinsfile-parallel-stage), I'm able to do the following after trying this script:

```
// main script block
// could use eg. params.parallel build parameter to choose parallel/serial 
def runParallel = true
def buildStages

node('master') {
  stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages') {
    // Set up List<Map<String,Closure>> describing the builds
    buildStages = prepareBuildStages()
    println("Initialised pipeline.")
  }

  for (builds in buildStages) {
    if (runParallel) {
      parallel(builds)
    } else {
      // run serially (nb. Map is unordered! )
      for (build in builds.values()) {
        build.call()
      }
    }
  }

  stage('Done') {
      println('The whole SHENZI is complete.')
  }
}

// Create List of build stages to suit
def prepareBuildStages() {
  def buildList = []

  for (i=1; i<4; i++) {
    def buildStages = [:]
    for (name in [ 'Alpha', 'Tango', 'Chyarli' ] ) {
      def n = "${name} ${i}"
      buildStages.put(n, prepareOneBuildStage(n))
    }
    buildList.add(buildStages)
  }
  return buildList
}

def prepareOneBuildStage(String name) {
    def proj_name = name.split(' ')[0]    
    def proj_parallel_sub_step = name.split(' ')[1]

    //Return the whole chunkoni
    return {
            stage("Build\nProject-${proj_name}\nStep ${proj_parallel_sub_step}") {
                println("Building ${proj_name} - ${proj_parallel_sub_step}")
                sh(script:'sleep 15', returnStatus:true)
            }
    }
}
```

When I'm putting the above Groovy Script (which is creating DYNAMIC Stages) inside `Pipeline Script` or `Pipeline Script from SCM` (i.e. the same code available in a .groovy file) -- it runs successfully and creates dynamic stages under BUILD step for each of the 3 projects and runs 3 steps (Nth) for all 3 projects in parallel and then starts the next Nth step for all 3 projects and so on.

If you see below, we also got individual columns in Jenkins job dashboard for them.

[image]

Now, When I put the above script in Jenkinsfile (Pipeline DSL) **where I have** `pipeline { .... }` section, it's not working and giving me the following error.

Using my JOB DSL, I created a new Jenkins Pipeline job where `Pipeline Script from SCM` calls a groovy file (which now contains):

```
//----------------------------------------------------
// Both - Parallel Run and GUI View in JF Jenkins job.
//----------------------------------------------------
def runParallel = true
def buildStages
def wkspace = /var/lib/jenkins/workspaces/ignore_this_variale_or_its_value_for_now

// Create List of build stages to suit
def prepareBuildStages() {
  def buildList = []

  for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
    def buildStages = [:]
    for (name in [ 'Alpha', 'Tango', 'Chyarli' ] ) {
      def n = "${name} ${i}"
      buildStages.put(n, prepareOneBuildStage(n))
    }
    buildList.add(buildStages)
  }
  return buildList
}
//---
def prepareOneBuildStage(String name) {
  def proj_name = name.split(' ')[0]
  def proj_parallel_sub_step = name.split(' ')[1]
  // return the whole chunkoni (i.e. for a given stage) - will be named dynamically.
  return {
    stage("Build\nProject-${proj_name}\nStep ${proj_parallel_sub_step}") {
      println("Building ${proj_name} - ${proj_parallel_sub_step}")
      sh(script:'sleep 15', returnStatus:true)
    }
  }
}
// Set up List<Map<String,Closure>> describing the builds
buildStages = prepareBuildStages()
//---------------------




String jenkinsBaselines

// SEE NOW --- we have this section called 'pipeline'
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'rhat6'
            customWorkspace wkspace
        }
    }

    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
        timeout(time: 8, unit: 'HOURS')
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }

    environment {
        someEnvVar = 'aValue'

    }

    //------------- Stages
    stages {
        stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages') {
            // Set up List<Map<String,Closure>> describing the builds
            println("Initialised pipeline.")
        }

        for (builds in buildStages) {
            if (runParallel) {
                parallel(builds)
            } else {
                // run serially (nb. Map is unordered! )
                for (build in builds.values()) {
                    build.call()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Done') {
            println('The whole SHENZI is complete.')
        }      
    }
    //---------------------
}
```

Running the Jenkinsfile Jenkins job now gives me this error:

```
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 1s
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 69: Not a valid stage section definition: "buildStages = prepareBuildStages()". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 69, column 5.
            stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 69: Unknown stage section "println". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a steps block. @ line 69, column 5.
            stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 75: Expected a stage @ line 75, column 5.
            for (builds in buildStages) {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 86: Unknown stage section "println". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a steps block. @ line 86, column 5.
            stage('Done') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 69: No "steps" or "parallel" to execute within stage "Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages" @ line 69, column 5.
            stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages') {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 86: No "steps" or "parallel" to execute within stage "Done" @ line 86, column 5.
            stage('Done') {
       ^

6 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:557)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:518)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:290)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I get this working in Jenkinsfile `pipeline` section and still able to get individual columns per dynamically created stage for a given project N and Step M?

Tried the following way, still errors the say way.

```
//------------- Stages
stages {
    stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages') {
        // Set up List<Map<String,Closure>> describing the builds
        buildStages = prepareBuildStages()
        println("Initialised pipeline.")

        // tried this way too. within a stage
        buildStages.each { bld -->
            parallel(bld)
        }  
    }

    stage('Done') {
        println('The whole SHENZI is complete.')
    }      
}
//---------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

So I did some poking into this and got it working.

The new code within Jenkinsfile (for **STAGES**) is now:

```
//------------- Stages
stages {
     stage('Start Pipeline') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh "echo HELLO moto razr!"
            }
        }  
     }

    stage('Initializing Parallel Dynamic Stages'){
        steps {
            script {
                // Run all Nth step for all Projects in Parallel. 
                buildStages.each { bs -> parallel(bs) }


                // OR uncomment the following code (if conditional on boolean variable).
                /*
                for (builds in buildStages) {
                    if (runParallel) {
                        parallel(builds)
                    } else {
                        // run serially (nb. Map is unordered! )
                        for (build in builds.values()) {
                            build.call()
                        }
                    }
                }
                */        

            }   
        }
     } 

    stage('Done') {
        println('The whole SHENZI is complete.')
    }      
}
//---------------------
```

That's all it took to work.

**For clear messages / stage names, I tweaked the function as well and We won't set this variable buildStages within `pipeline { ... }`**

```
//---
def prepareOneBuildStage(String name) {
  def proj_name = name.split(' ')[0]
  def proj_parallel_sub_step = name.split(' ')[1]
  // return the whole chunkoni (i.e. for a given stage) - will be named dynamically.
  return {
    stage("BUILD Project-${proj_name} Parallel_Step_${proj_parallel_sub_step}") {
      println("Parallel_Step # ${proj_parallel_sub_step} of Project => ${proj_name}")
      sh(script:"echo \"Parallel_Step # ${proj_parallel_sub_step} of Project => ${proj_name}\" && sleep 20", returnStatus:true)
      // -- OR -- you can call Gradle task i.e. rpm / any other / any other command here. 
    }
  }
}

// Set up List<Map<String,Closure>> describing the builds. section now.
buildStages = prepareBuildStages()
//---------------------
```

This implementation is now creating **N** no. of **parallel stages** i.e. a **separate column per project** for a **given Nth step** (*when looking at Jenkinsfile job's dashboard*) for P no. of projects.

1. It will run **All P projects** for a given **N**th step in parallel.
2. It will **wait for Nth step for all Projects** to **complete first** and then jump to the next Nth step.

   What this means is, if Project ALPHA Step #1 is complete, it'll still wait for all Step #1 of other 2 projects and then launch Step #2 of all projects in parallel.
3. **Challenge:** How can we make ALPHA Project's Step #2 to start as soon as ALPHA project's Step #1 is complete i.e. it won't wait for Step 1 of other 2 projects to complete and could possibly run Step #2 of ALPHA project 1 in parallel with Step N(=1) or N+1 of other projects.

   *This assumes all projects are independent of each other and projects don't share contents generated by a given project/their stage/steps in any other project/stage/step.*

**Depending upon your own requirements**, you may want to wait (i.e. don't run Step 2 of all projects until **Step 1 of all projects** are fully complete) **--OR--** you may want to run **Step 2 of ALPHA** project with let's say - **Step 2 of TANGO** project **while project CHYARLI's step 1 is still in progress**.

As the main scope of this post was to get separate dynamically created columns/stages per project (running in parallel within `pipeline { ... }` section), I think, I got what I was looking for.

**NOTE**: Go easy with parallel if you want to run concurrent builds of a pipeline. For more info about issues related to **running** `parallel` build actions **concurrently**, see here: [Jenkins - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits & Gradle error: Task 'null' not found in root project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797696/jenkins-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-last-unit-does-not-have-enough-val)

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the stages parallel as follow

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'master' } } 
    stages {
        stage('Add regression tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def testList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
                    def branches = [:] 
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
                           int index=i, branch = i+1
                           stage ("branch_${branch}"){ 
                                branches["branch_${branch}"] = { 
                                    node ('master'){
                                        sh "echo 'node: ${NODE_NAME},  index: ${index}, i: ${i}, testListVal: " + testList[index] + "'"
                                    }
                                }
                          }
                    }
                    
                    parallel branches
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).